# Get MAX(LastUploadDate) IF BatchUpload IS NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Every time we upload an invoice I need to run `INSERT INTO tblVersapayInvoice`:

| CustomerID | LastUploadDate | BillNum | BatchUpload |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1433 | 2023-09-25 09:21:32.010 | 229985 | NULL |
| 1433 | 2023-09-26 09:21:32.010 | 229985 | NULL |
| 1433 | 2023-09-27 09:21:32.010 | 229985 | NULL |
| 1433 | NULL | 229985 | Y |
| 1433 | 2023-09-27 09:21:32.010 | 240022 | NULL |
| 1447 | 2023-09-22 09:21:32.010 | 230071 | NULL |
| 1447 | 2023-09-25 09:21:32.010 | 230071 | NULL |

As you can see I have uploaded Bill_Num 229985 and 230071 multiple times and 240022 only once. I want the `MAX(LastUploadDate)` if the BatchUpload IS NULL, otherwise I want ‘Batch’ in the result set.

This is my desired result (I tried to show it in a table but it didn't work):

```
Bill_NUM 240022 2023-09-27 09:21:32.010
Bill_NUM 229985 Batch
Bill_NUM 230071 2023-09-25 09:21:32.010
```

Here is my query but it gives me a row for the BatchUpload = Y and a row for the Max(LastUploadDate). I only want 1 row for each Bill_Num.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN BatchUpload IS NOT NULL THEN 'Batch' 
        ELSE CONVERT(varchar, MAX(LastUploadDate), 1) 
    END AS LastUploadDate, 
    Bill_Num 
FROM 
    tblVersapayInvoice 
GROUP BY 
    Bill_Num, BatchUpload
```

Comment: I hesitate to ask. .....but why are the entries duplicated in the first place?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you only want one row per `Bill_Num`, then `BatchUpload` shouldn't be in the `GROUP BY`. Maybe you meant:

```
SELECT Bill_Num, CASE MAX(BatchUpload) 
    WHEN 'Y' THEN 'Batch' 
    ELSE CONVERT(varchar(30), MAX(LastUploadDate), 120) 
  END AS LastUploadDate
FROM dbo.tblVersapayInvoice  
GROUP BY Bill_Num;
```

- [Example db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_r-U56Dd)

Comment: I did try taking the BatchUpload out of the Group By but I would get an error. I do see that your CASE statement is different than mine. Yours works. Thank you!!!!